# API returns 1 profile data when array is passed

Tags: php, api, curl

I am stuck on this for past 1 days and can't seem to get it to work. When I pass the array of userIds to `profilesearch` I only get 1 result back from the APi.

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

```
class Players{

    public $username = "username";
    public $password = "password";
    public $base_url = "https://www.example.com/api/v1";
    public $userIds = [];

    //This is the first method that fires of to get the userId
    public function usersearch(){
        $url = $this->base_url . '/usersearch?informat=json&format=json';
        $request = '{"identification":[]}';
        $username = $this->username;
        $password = $this->password;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: UTF-8"),
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username:$password",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH => true,
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            var_dump(curl_error($ch), 'cURL Errors');
            curl_close($ch);
        } else {
            $result = array();
            $result = json_decode($response, true);
            $result = $result['results'][0]['results'];
            //Now that we have the list of users, loop over it and get their userId and save it in the userIds property as in array
            foreach($result as $key => $item){
                $this->userIds[] = $item['userId'];
            }
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        //Let's go and grab the profile data
        $this->profilesearch();
    }

    public function profilesearch(){
        //Make a local variable of the property userIds which contains list of userIds in array format
        $userIds = $this->userIds;
        $userIds = implode(',', $userIds); //This becomes "101,239,240"
        $url = $this->base_url . '/profilesearch?informat=json&format=json';
        $request = '{"formNames":["Athlete Summary"],"userIds":[' . $userIds . ']}'; //This becomes {"formNames":["Athlete Summary"],"userIds":[101,239,240]}
        $username = $this->username;
        $password = $this->password;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: UTF-8"),
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username:$password",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH => true,
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            var_dump(curl_error($ch), 'cURL Errors');
        } else {
            $result = array();
            $result = json_decode($response, true);
            var_dump( $result ); //I get only one user data
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the API probably expects another JSON format. But I would recommend to
not craft a JSON string by hand you should use instead `json_encode` to build the
JSON string i.e.:

```
$request = json_encode([
    'formNames' => ['Athlete Summary'],
    'userIds' => $userIds,
]);
```